# Chain API call cascade, pass second value as third call argument, "id is not a valid integer"

Tags: api, relationships, developer, chaining

While making a cascade API call, a roadblock has been hit, here's a code:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => "id",
  'id' => array('IN' => array(168, 169)),

 // Second call

    'api.Relationship.get' => array(
      'return' => "contact_id_a",
      'contact_id_b' => "\$value.id",
      'relationship_type_id' => 4,
      'is_permission_b_a' => "1"),

          // Third call

        'api.Contact.get' => array('id' => array(
           'IN' => array("\$value.api.relationship.get"))), // <-- here
));
```

It returns

```
{
    "error_field": "id",
    "type": "integer",
    "error_code": 2001,
    "entity": "Contact",
    "action": "get",
    "is_error": 1,
    "error_message": "Error in call to Contact_get : id is not a valid integer"
}
```

What exactly returns third call and how these results should be properly "plugged in" to get correct output? Thanks anyone for any bit of advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you are trying to fetch the details of contacts that are related to the ones you search for first?
The $value refers to the last call in a nested one.

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => "id",
  'api.Relationship.get' 
   => array(
     'contact_id_a' => "\$value.id",
     'api.contact.get' => "\$value.contact_id_b"),
));
```

If you want to give more params to the inner api.contact.get:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => "id",
  'api.Relationship.get' 
   => array('contact_id_a' => "\$value.id", 
     'api.contact.get' 
      => array(
        'id' => "\$value.contact_id_b", 
        'sequential' => 1, 
        'return' => "display_name"
      )
    ),
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks a mil for response, Xavier. Shall have a closer look at it, since it has turned to be related to another question i've asked here http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9086/entityref-widget-seems-to-not-respecting-params : recent discoveries show, that there is same "id is not a proper integer"  error popped up. So, hopefully, cracking this one, both will be targeted and resolved.